# Materialize Parallax not showing images in Angular2 application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, materialize

I'm building a webpage with Angular 2 and Materialize CSS; however, when I try to use the Materialize's parallax feature, the images do not show

Here's my Angular2 Component Class:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/1425/500" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
    <div id="index-banner" class="parallax-container">
      <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br>
          <h1 class="header center teal-text text-lighten-2">Parallax Template</h1>
          <div class="row center">
            <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="row center">
            <a href="http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html" id="download-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light teal lighten-1">Get Started</a>
          </div>
          <br><br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1425/500" alt="Unsplashed background img 1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <!--   Icon Section   -->
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="icon-block">
              <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">flash_on</i></h2>
              <h5 class="center">Speeds up development</h5>
              <p class="light">We did most of the heavy lifting for you to provide a default stylings that incorporate our custom components. Additionally, we refined animations and transitions to provide a smoother experience for developers.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="icon-block">
              <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">group</i></h2>
              <h5 class="center">User Experience Focused</h5>
              <p class="light">By utilizing elements and principles of Material Design, we were able to create a framework that incorporates components and animations that provide more feedback to users. Additionally, a single underlying responsive system across all platforms allow for a more unified user experience.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12 m4">
            <div class="icon-block">
              <h2 class="center brown-text"><i class="material-icons">settings</i></h2>
              <h5 class="center">Easy to work with</h5>
              <p class="light">We have provided detailed documentation as well as specific code examples to help new users get started. We are also always open to feedback and can answer any questions a user may have about Materialize.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
      <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row center">
            <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax"><img src="background2.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="section">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12 center">
            <h3><i class="mdi-content-send brown-text"></i></h3>
            <h4>Contact Us</h4>
            <p class="left-align light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam scelerisque id nunc nec volutpat. Etiam pellentesque tristique arcu, non consequat magna fermentum ac. Cras ut ultricies eros. Maecenas eros justo, ullamcorper a sapien id, viverra ultrices eros. Morbi sem neque, posuere et pretium eget, bibendum sollicitudin lacus. Aliquam eleifend sollicitudin diam, eu mattis nisl maximus sed. Nulla imperdiet semper molestie. Morbi massa odio, condimentum sed ipsum ac, gravida ultrices erat. Nullam eget dignissim mauris, non tristique erat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
      <div class="section no-pad-bot">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row center">
            <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax"><img src="http://materializecss.com/templates/parallax-template/background3.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 3"></div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

As you may have noticed, The first line in my template is an image tag. This image tag works correctly.

However, the other image tags within the parallax container do not work correctly, and whether or not they are locally stored or an external resource doesn't matter.

In my index.html file I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="blue darken-4" role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper container light"><a id="logo-container" href="/" class="brand-logo">My App</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
    <footer class="page-footer blue darken-4">
      <div class="footer-copyright">
        <div class="container">
          Made by Materialize
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In here, besides including Materialize, Jquery, and Angular2's stuff, I have included two files: styles.css and main.js.

styles.css includes the parallax template's CSS. And the following code belongs to main.js

```
(function($){
  $(function(){

    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
    $('.parallax').parallax();

  }); // end of document ready
})(jQuery); // end of jQuery name space
```

I can't see any reason for my code not to work, but it isn't. Where have I gone wrong?

While inspecting my app in Chrome, I found that the images had been found with NO 404 errors. The app just doesn't seem to be displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

**For paralax use this  code:**

```
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax" materialize="parallax"><img src="http://materializecss.com/images/parallax1.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="section white">
  <div class="row container">
    <h2 class="header">Parallax</h2>
    <p class="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while scrolling.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parallax-container">
  <div class="parallax" materialize="parallax"><img src="http://materializecss.com/images/parallax2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**For Sidnav use this code**

```
    <nav  role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper container">
        <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav" >
          <li><a href="#">Navbar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" materialize="sideNav" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```